# SQL Get common values by grouping rows

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
| uid | group_id | 
-----------------
|   1 |     1    |
|   1 |     2    |
|   1 |     3    |
|   1 |     4    |
|   2 |     1    |
|   2 |     2    |
|   2 |     3    |
|   3 |     1    |
|   3 |     2    |
|   3 |     4    |
...
```

How can I get the common set of `group_ids` for some set of `uids`.

For e.g. 
for uid 1,2 : The common group_ids are 1,2,3
for uid 1,2,3 : The common group_ids are 1 and 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming each `group_ID` is unique for every `uid`, (*otherwise you need to use `distinct`*)

```
SELECT group_ID
FROM tableName
WHERE uid IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY group_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo (*includes two queries*)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52cc8/3)